# User in sudo group cannot use sudo command

Tags: 14.04, sudo

I have a user, `supersecretuser`, that is in the `sudo` group, but doesn't have `sudo` access. Is there something else that needs to be done to give this user `sudo` access?

```
$ ssh supersecretuser@myserver
supersecretuser@myserver:~$ groups
supersecretuser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
supersecretuser@myserver:~$ sudo vim install.sh 
[sudo] password for supersecretuser: 
supersecretuser is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

`supersecretuser` is the user we setup when doing the Ubuntu install.

Comment: Did `supersecretuser` log out and back in (or at least start a new login shell e.g. `su - supersecretuser`) since being added to the `sudo` group?

Comment: When I ssh in as `supersecretuser`, I can see that it is in the `sudo` group. Is there something else I need to do to log out? Added ssh into server to question.

Comment: If you have another superuser, I would try adding `suspersecretuser` to the `sudo` group again. `sudo adduser supersecretuser sudo`. You might get error like `user is already in group sudo`, but its worth a shot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you error message says your user `is not in the sudoers file`, could you please check your `/etc/sudoers` file, see if there is such a line:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

If this line is missing, users in the `sudo` group will not be sudoers.  Edit the file using `visudo` command (checks for correct synthax and locks the file).

You can also try to add a customized line like this:

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Replace `root` with your username, reboot, and try if it works.

Comment: I can't `sudo` to see this file to say this is 100% the problem. However, based on our chef script that we use on other servers, I can see we aren't adding `supersecretuser` user to `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I had `sudo` and `admin` record but they were not prefixed with a `%`.

Answer (score 10):

As per your conversation with @steeldriver in the comments, my guess is that your user isn't logged off.

The easiest way to make sure that the `supersecretuser` has logged off is to type into terminal, as another user, `who`.

When doing so, I get output like this:

```
mitch@quartz:~$ who
mitch    :0           2014-09-08 09:49 (:0)
mitch    pts/0        2014-09-08 13:18 (:0.0)
```

I only see myself. Similarly, typing `w` into a terminal shows me who all is logged on and what they're doing:

```
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
mitch    :0       :0               09:49   ?xdm?  29:08   0.11s init --user
mitch    pts/0    :0.0             13:18    5.00s  0.06s  0.01s w
```

You can STOP your other user, (SSU I'll call it) with the following command:

```
pkill -STOP -u SSU
```

However, truthfully, the easiest solution would be to just reboot the system if that's possible.

Comment: Rebooted the server, and I don't have `sudo` access.

Comment: So you lost the ability for your user to ssh into the server?

Comment: Sorry, updated comment. Can still ssh into the server, just not `sudo` access.

Comment: Can you update the original post with the method you used to grant sudo access to the user?

Comment: `supersecretuser` is the user we setup when doing the Ubuntu install.

Comment: In my case I used Debian's very, very limited user management applet to change my account to an "Adminstrator" account and still couldn't sudo (right away). Based on this thread and others, I used the `id myaccountname` to see that I was actually in the sudo group and I saw that sudo was a group mentioned in /etc/sudoers. Then I did `su - myaccountname` and then `sudo ls` and that worked as expected. Thus it was confirmed that I could sudo but to have full use of the capability I would have to log out and then log in. And the error message is not well-chosen.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add a supersecretuser to sudo group is `sudo gpasswd -a supersecretuser sudo` and have supersecretuser log out/back in; but if you have lost the ability to sudo, I'm afraid you'll have to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

## Reboot your system

It may seem silly to post this as an answer, but I wasted ages trying to figure out why my system (Debian 12) continued to tell me that my user was not in the sudoers file even after running the following commands.

```bash
# NOTE: do not ignore the `-` !
# usermod does not work without it
user@computer:$ su -
root@computer:$ usermod -aG sudo user
```

Rebooting fixed the issue. No changes are required to the file `/etc/sudoers`.

Answer (score -1):

After you have checked that file privileges are right:

```
-r--r----- 1 root root x x x x:x /etc/sudoers
```

You most probably have lost the `s`-bit on file executable, it should read:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 2 root root x x x  x /usr/bin/sudo
```

if it doesn't: with root privileges give `

```
chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

and you
should be okay.. unless you know you have altered the `sudoers` file yourself! :)

Comment: -1 Issues with the file permissions of the `sudo` binary and `sudoers` configuration result in different error messages than those in the question. They would literally refer to inappropriate file permissions.